# Are there any online Python IDE's that have the built-in modules available?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

There are bunch of online Python editors that I have found, but none of them have any modules available. Are there any IDE's available online that have simple modules such as `math` and `random` built in?

Comment: [Replit](https://replit.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i didn't tested any variety of online python interpreters, but a quick experiment yields this [Website](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/online-compiler/). It can run your basic and even some advance built-in modules

Test code is following

```
# Online Python compiler (interpreter) to run Python online.
# Write Python 3 code in this online editor and run it.
import random

#testing a random built-in module
marks = {
    "English": random.randint(1, 100),
    "Bio": random.randint(1, 100),
    "Botany": random.randint(1, 100),
    "Literature": random.randint(1, 100),
}

for mark in marks.keys():
    print("You got ", marks[mark] , " marks in ", mark)

#testing the built-in sum function
total = sum([marks[subject] for subject in marks.keys()])
print("Total Marks", total)
```

and the output is following

[image]